# How to get a CodeSignature for a Mac OS X app

Tags: cocoa, macos, codesign

Hey! I think this is a simple question for you. Most of the system apps and also some third-party apps have integrated a CodeSignature in their bundle. I heard with such a CodeSignature the system would not ask anymore for accepting incoming network connections (if the firewall is enabled). Now the question is where to get such a CodeSignature...
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Where and how to get code signed?*

See [Code Signing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> Code signing is a technology
>   introduced in Mac OS X v10.5 that
>   ensures the integrity of code and
>   allows the system to recognize updated
>   versions of code as the same program
>   as the original. Once you have signed
>   your code, any change in the code that
>   you did not intend—whether introduced
>   accidently or by hackers—can be
>   detected by the system. On the other
>   hand, your signature on an updated
>   version of your program tells the
>   system to treat the new version
>   exactly as it treated the old, so that
>   users are not bothered with obscure
>   dialogs asking them to give permission
>   to the keychain or some other system
>   component to interact with your code.
>
> Signing code is fast, requires few
>   resources, and increases the size of
>   your deliverable by less than 1%.
>   Signatures do not alter how your code
>   runs and are ignored by Mac OS X
>   versions prior to Mac OS X v10.5;
>   therefore, there is no reason not to
>   sign your code. However, there are a
>   few things you need to know before you
>   begin. This document explains the
>   terminology and concepts you need to
>   know and gives you a few
>   straightforward procedures you can
>   follow to sign your code.
>
> Because the system will expect all
>   code to be signed, any code that is
>   not signed will not behave in the same
>   manner as the majority of the programs
>   on the user’s system. In particular,
>   the user is likely to be bothered with
>   additional dialog boxes and prompts
>   for unsigned code that they don’t see
>   with signed code, and unsigned code
>   might not work as expected with some
>   system components, such as parental
>   controls. It is highly recommended
>   that you sign all code intended for
>   use with Mac OS X v10.5 or later.
>
> Therefore, if you are delivering, or
>   intend to deliver, code that might
>   ever be run on Mac OS X v10.5 or
>   later, you should read this document.

[Code Signing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)